# Jcarousel- Unable to add separate captions below images in that scrolls together with the image

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, jcarousel

I wish to add captions in a div below each image so that the caption scrolls with the carousel and has a hover change color effect.

I did it as so:

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" />
  <div class = "labelbox">
            <span class ="label"> FLOWER! </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

However, jcarousel does not account for caption height and **cuts off** all of the caption.

Is there anyway to make carousel wider so that the captions appear and scroll together with the image?

Comment: These are screenshots for of the problem:   [How it looks like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8fD.png)   [Decreased height of image to reveal caption](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VwQyf.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is your css for that element and it's parent?

```
Be sure sure that the height of your <li> is that of your <img> + <div class="labelbox>.
```